# Only one frequency in my R daily time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have data frame (df) that looks like this:

[image]

It includes complete data from 2013-01-01 to 2017-05-04.

I'm trying to turn it into a daily time series object.

```
ts_day <- as.ts(df$units_sold, start = c(2013,1), end = c(2017,124), freq = 365)
ts_day
```

However, it says there is only one frequency. I.e.,

[image]

And when I try to use the stl function, it doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying only the end or only the start, not both?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for the suggestion. I tried only the end or only the start and the results are the same.

Comment: Not sure but I think ts can't handle leap years so that might be messing up your data. Did you try zoo or xts?

Comment: What if you try `ts` in place of `as.ts`?

Comment: @RichardHardy Wahoo! Changing it to ts fixed it. Thank you!